# Creating self relation in prisma

Tags: prisma

I want to add a self relation on my `user` table but it seems there is an issue with the way am doing it.

```
model User {
  id                BigInt                  @id(map: "user_pkey") @unique(map: "user_id_key") @default(autoincrement())
  firstname         String?                 @db.VarChar
  lastname          String?                 @db.VarChar
  username          String?                 @unique @db.VarChar
  email             String?                 @db.VarChar
  password          String?                 @db.VarChar
  organization      String?                 @db.VarChar
  createdAt         DateTime?               @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt         DateTime?               @db.Timestamptz(6)
  parent_id         BigInt?                 
  deletedAt         DateTime?               @db.Timestamptz(6)
  deleted_by        BigInt?  

  
  @@map("users")

  parent            User?                   @relation(fields: [parent_id], references: [id]) // this line gives me error
}
```

I see the following error :
```Error validating field `parent` in model `User`: The relation field `parent` on model `User` is missing an opposite relation field on the model `User`. Either run `prisma format` or add it manually.

```
What am i doing wrong here?
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this schema?

```
model User {
  id             BigInt    @id(map: "user_pkey") @unique(map: "user_id_key") @default(autoincrement())
  firstname      String?   @db.VarChar
  lastname       String?   @db.VarChar
  username       String?   @unique @db.VarChar
  email          String?   @db.VarChar
  password       String?   @db.VarChar
  organization   String?   @db.VarChar
  createdAt      DateTime? @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt      DateTime? @db.Timestamptz(6)
  parent_id      BigInt?
  deletedAt      DateTime? @db.Timestamptz(6)
  deleted_by     BigInt?
  parent         User?     @relation("UserParent", fields: [parent_id], references: [id]) // this line gives me error
  usersAsParents User[]    @relation("UserParent")

  @@map("users")
}
```

For reference, here is a guide on [Self-Relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations).